# Multi-layer PyQt4 image viewer

Tags: python, performance, gui, pyqt

I have written a functional GUI program using PyQt4, and I'm looking for some feedback because it's not as fast as I would like.  It takes in some number of large, same-sized 2D arrays and displays a sub-image of each one in its own sub-window - at full resolution or only zoomed by a factor of 2 or 4.  The central GUI contains one of the complete images down-sampled so it fits on the screen, on which is a movable selection box that can be moved by mouse or by the arrow keys.

The response when I move the box is slow when I set the sub-window zoom level to 25% or 50%, is there a way to speed it up?  I also could not get around creating a sub-class of `QtGraphicsView` for the central widget, is that the most proper way to do this?

The primary code - it's decently long, but I've removed some other functional settings (such as the color of the box) to bring the line count down:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ajsutil import get_screen_size, bytescale, clamp, upsamp, downsamp


# This is used as the central widget in the main GUI
class SubView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    """A sub-class of QGraphicsView that allows specific mouse and keyboard
    handling.
    """

    # Custom signals - one for keyboard update and one for mouse update
    updateEvent = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    modEvent = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, img, boxsize):
        """Initialize the class with an image and a box size."""

        super(SubView,self).__init__()

        wdims = (img.size().width(), img.size().height())
        self.bs = boxsize

        # Construct a scene with a pixmap and a rectangle
        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(0, 0, wdims[0], wdims[1])
        self.px = scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img))

        self.rpen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green)
        self.rect = scene.addRect(0, 0, boxsize,boxsize, pen=self.rpen)

        self.setScene(scene)

        # Set size policies and settings
        self.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed,
                           QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.setMinimumSize(wdims[0], wdims[1])
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.mouseOn = False

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """If the box is picked up, move the box."""
        if self.mouseOn:
            self.updateEvent.emit([event.x(), event.y()])

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """Pick up or drop the box."""
        self.mouseOn = not self.mouseOn

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        """Move the box with arrow keys."""
        if not self.mouseOn:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
                mod = [0,-1]
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
                mod = [0,1]
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
                mod = [-1,0]
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
                mod = [1,0]
            self.modEvent.emit([x*self.bs/2 for x in mod])


# This is the main GUI!!
class ImageViewerQt(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """An image viewer for displaying a large image, or set of images, with a
    zoom box that can be dragged with the mouse or moved with arrow keys.
    Small sub-windows show the full-resolution image(s) downsampled by factors
    of up to 4.

    Uses a large QGraphicsView subclass as the central widget, with a status
    bar under it.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create the Qt application (if necessary)
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
        if self.app is None:
            self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        super(ImageViewerQt,self).__init__()

        # Define member attributes
        # (I'm using dictionaries to avoid having tons of little attributes,
        #  but there may be a better way ....)
        self.acts = {}
        self.info = {}

        boxsize = kwargs.get('boxsize', 512)
        self.info['boxsize'] = boxsize
        self.info['zoom'] = 1.0

        # Construct a list from the input images
        nimgs = len(args)
        self.imgList = []
        if nimgs == 0:
            self.imgList.append(np.zeros((1024,1024)))
            self.nimgs = 1
        else:
            for indata in args:
                self.imgList.append(indata)
            self.nimgs = nimgs
        self.names = kwargs.get('names', ["Image %d" % (i+1) for i in
                                            range(nimgs)])

        # Set up sizes - try to automatically place the big window and smaller
        # window so that they don't overlap
        data = self.imgList[0]
        dims = np.array(data.shape)
        scrdims = get_screen_size()
        scales = np.ceil(dims.astype(np.float32) / scrdims)
        scale = np.amax(scales).astype(np.float)
        wdims = dims / scale
        if (scrdims[0]-boxsize) > (scrdims[1]-boxsize):
            xoff = wdims[0]+30
            yoff = 30
        else:
            xoff = 5
            yoff = wdims[1]+30
        nxwin = int((scrdims[0]-xoff) / (boxsize+25))

        self.dims = dims
        self.wdims = wdims
        self.info['scale'] = scale
        self.info['xy'] = [boxsize/2, boxsize/2]

        # Initialize the vmin/vmax for the small window grayscales and
        # set up the float-to-byte conversion function
        ominv = data.min()
        omaxv = data.max()
        self.info['sm_bounds'] = [ominv,omaxv]
        self.info['sm_minmax'] = [ominv,omaxv]
        self.smbytefunc = lambda x: 255. * (x - ominv) / (omaxv - ominv)

        # Initialize the vmin/vmax for the big window grayscale and
        # set up the float-to-byte conversion function
        ddata = downsamp(data, scale)
        minv = ddata.min()
        maxv = ddata.max()
        self.info['img_bounds'] = [minv,maxv]
        self.info['img_minmax'] = [minv,maxv]
        self.tobytefunc = lambda x: 255. * (x - minv) / (maxv - minv)

        # Define grayscale color scales
        self.colortable = [QtGui.qRgb(i, i, i) for i in xrange(256)]
        self.smcolortable = [QtGui.qRgb(i, i, i) for i in xrange(256)]

        # Construct the QImage used for the big window
        self.img = QtGui.QImage(bytescale(ddata).astype(np.uint8),
                                wdims[0], wdims[1],
                                QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
        self.img.setColorTable(self.colortable)

        # Set up the view
        self.view = SubView(self.img, boxsize/scale)
        self.view.updateEvent.connect(self.updateView)
        self.view.modEvent.connect(self.modView)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        self.sB = self.statusBar()
        self.sB.showMessage("Ready")
        self.setWindowTitle('Image Viewer')
        self.setGeometry(10,30,2000,2000)
        self.resize(self.sizeHint())

        self.createActions()
        self.createMenus()

        self.createSubWindows(xoff, yoff, nxwin)

        self.show()
        self.app.exec_()

    def save(self):
        """Save the big image to an image file."""
        fname, ffilter = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        self.view.px.pixmap().save(fname)

    def quit(self):
        """Exit the GUI."""
        for i_img in range(self.nimgs):
            self.smid[i_img].close()
        self.close()

    def createActions(self):
        """Create the actions for the menus."""
        # File menu
        self.acts['save'] = QtGui.QAction("&Save Image",self,triggered=self.save)
        self.acts['exit'] = QtGui.QAction("E&xit",self,triggered=self.quit)

        # Zoom option
        self.acts['zoomGroup'] = QtGui.QActionGroup(self)
        self.acts['zoom200'] = QtGui.QAction("200%",
            self.acts['zoomGroup'], checkable=True)
        self.acts['zoom200'].setData(0.5)
        self.acts['zoom100'] = QtGui.QAction("100%",
            self.acts['zoomGroup'], checkable=True)
        self.acts['zoom100'].setData(1.0)
        self.acts['zoom050'] = QtGui.QAction(" 50%",
            self.acts['zoomGroup'], checkable=True)
        self.acts['zoom050'].setData(2.0)
        self.acts['zoom025'] = QtGui.QAction(" 25%",
            self.acts['zoomGroup'], checkable=True)
        self.acts['zoom025'].setData(4.0)
        self.acts['zoom100'].setChecked(True)
        self.acts['zoomGroup'].triggered.connect(self.setZoom)

    def createMenus(self):
        """Create the menu buttons."""
        self.fileMenu = QtGui.QMenu("&File", self)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.acts['save'])
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.acts['exit'])

        self.optMenu = QtGui.QMenu("&Options", self)

        self.zoomMenu = QtGui.QMenu("&Zoom", self)
        self.zoomMenu.addAction(self.acts['zoom200'])
        self.zoomMenu.addAction(self.acts['zoom100'])
        self.zoomMenu.addAction(self.acts['zoom050'])
        self.zoomMenu.addAction(self.acts['zoom025'])
        self.optMenu.addMenu(self.zoomMenu)

        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.fileMenu)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.optMenu)

    def createSubWindows(self, xoff, yoff, nxwin):
        """Create the individual sub-windows containing the full-resolution
        images.
        """
        # Make lists to hold the ids, labels, and images themselves
        self.smid = []
        self.smlbl = []
        self.smimg = []

        bs = self.info['boxsize']
        mn = self.info['sm_minmax'][0]
        mx = self.info['sm_minmax'][1]

        # For each image, construct a QWidget, a QImage, and a QLabel to hold it
        for i_img in range(self.nimgs):
            self.smid.append(QtGui.QWidget(self))
            self.smid[i_img].setWindowTitle(self.names[i_img])
            self.smid[i_img].setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)

            patch = self.imgList[i_img][0:bs,0:bs]
            patch = bytescale(patch, vmin=mn, vmax=mx).astype(np.uint8)
            img = QtGui.QImage(patch,bs,bs,QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
            img.setColorTable(self.colortable)
            self.smimg.append(img)

            self.smlbl.append(QtGui.QLabel(self.smid[i_img]))
            self.smlbl[i_img].setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img))
            self.smlbl[i_img].setMinimumSize(bs,bs)

            w, h = (self.smlbl[i_img].sizeHint().width(),
                    self.smlbl[i_img].sizeHint().height())
            xo = xoff + (i_img % nxwin)*(bs+25)
            yo = yoff + (i_img / nxwin)*(bs+45)
            self.smid[i_img].setGeometry(xo,yo,w,h)

            self.smid[i_img].show()

    def setZoom(self):
        """Zoom setting slot."""
        currAct = self.acts['zoomGroup'].checkedAction()
        currzoom = currAct.data()
        if np.isscalar(currzoom):
            self.info['zoom'] = currzoom
        else:
            self.info['zoom'] = currzoom.toFloat()[0]

        self.updateView()

    def modView(self, offxy):
        """Arrow-key control slot."""
        wxy = self.info['xy'] / self.info['scale']
        newxy = [wxy[i]+offxy[i] for i in range(len(wxy))]
        self.updateView(newxy)

    def updateView(self, wxy=None):
        """Update the entire GUI based on new box position or setting change."""
        if wxy is None:
            wxy = self.info['xy'] / self.info['scale']

        xy = [x * self.info['scale'] for x in wxy]

        bs = self.info['boxsize']
        bs2 = bs/2
        zm = self.info['zoom']

        xc = clamp(xy[0], [bs2*zm, self.dims[0]-bs2*zm])
        yc = clamp(xy[1], [bs2*zm, self.dims[1]-bs2*zm])
        self.info['xy'] = [xc,yc]

        wxc = xc / self.info['scale']
        wyc = yc / self.info['scale']
        wbs = bs / self.info['scale']
        wbs2 = bs2 / self.info['scale']

        self.view.rect.setRect(wxc-wbs2*zm,wyc-wbs2*zm,wbs*zm,wbs*zm)

        bbox = [yc-bs2*zm, xc-bs2*zm, yc+bs2*zm, xc+bs2*zm]
        mnmx = self.info['sm_minmax']
        for i_img in range(self.nimgs):
            data = self.imgList[i_img]
            patch = data[bbox[0]:bbox[2], bbox[1]:bbox[3]]
            if zm < 1:
                patch = upsamp(patch, 1.0/zm)
            else:
                patch = downsamp(patch, zm)
            patch = bytescale(patch, vmin=mnmx[0], vmax=mnmx[1]).astype(np.uint8)
            img = QtGui.QImage(patch,bs,bs,QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
            img.setColorTable(self.colortable)
            self.smimg[i_img] = img

            self.smlbl[i_img].setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img))

        status = "(%d, %d)" % (xc, yc)
        self.sB.showMessage(status)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from PIL import Image
    testfile = "path to filename"
    data = np.array(Image.open(testfile))
    red = data[:,:,0]
    grn = data[:,:,1]
    blu = data[:,:,2]
    iv = ImageViewerQt(red, grn, blu, names=['Red','Green','Blue'], boxsize=256)
```

For completeness, `ajsutil.py` contains:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import collections
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

def get_screen_size():
    """Return a tuple containing the size of the current monitor in pixels."""
    root = tk.Tk()

    scrwid = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    scrhgt = root.winfo_screenheight()

    root.destroy()

    return scrwid, scrhgt-90

def clamp(data, mnmx):
    """Clamp data to within specified range."""
    data = np.maximum(data, mnmx[0])
    data = np.minimum(data, mnmx[1])
    return data

def upsamp(data, scales):
    """Up-sample by separate scale factors in each dimension."""
    # Calculate new dimensions
    if not (isinstance(scales, collections.Sequence) or
            isinstance(scales, np.ndarray)):
        scales = np.tile(scales, data.ndim)

    # Set up new dimensions and replicate data
    new = np.copy(data)
    for idim in range(new.ndim):
        new = new.repeat(scales[idim], axis=idim)
    return new

def bytescale(data, vmin=None, vmax=None):
    """Scale data to 0-255."""
    if vmin == None:
        mn = np.amin(data)
    else:
        mn = vmin
    if vmax == None:
        mx = np.amax(data)
    else:
        mx = vmax

    out = np.array(255. * (data - mn) / (mx - mn))
    return out

def downsamp(data, scales):
    """Downsample by separate scale factors in each dimension."""
    # Calculate new dimensions
    dims = np.shape(data)
    ndim = np.ndim(data)
    if not (isinstance(scales, collections.Sequence) or
            isinstance(scales, np.ndarray)):
        scales = np.tile(scales, ndim)
    newdims = [np.floor(dims[i]/scales[i]) for i in range(ndim)]

    # If the scale does not divide exactly into dims, chop off the necessary
    # last elements before reshaping
    slices = []
    for i in range(ndim):
        slices.append(slice(newdims[i]*scales[i]))
    new = np.copy(data[slices])

    # Set up new dimensions and reshape the data
    sh = [newdims[0], scales[0]]
    for idim in range(1, new.ndim):
        sh.append(newdims[idim])
        sh.append(scales[idim])
    new = new.reshape(sh)

    # Average over the combining dimensions
    for idim in range(np.ndim(data)*2-1, 0, -2):
        new = new.mean(idim)
    return new
```

It can be tested with an example file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByA5ewXzeDztc09vbUw1R0dPUU0/view?usp=sharing), by running the main file (there is a `__name__ == "__main__"` statement at the bottom where you can set the path to the file).

It now runs under both Python 2 and Python 3, but it is still slow when the zoom factor is set.

Comment: Aw ... *sniff*, no takers?  I didn't even get to get the Tumbleweed badge.  Is it just that it's too long?

Comment: I had to change signal to pyqtSignal and change np.zeros(1024,1024) to np.zeros((1024,1024)) to get it to run.  You code was incomplete, so it makes is difficult to get it working.  I would recommend providing a complete working source (albeit shrunk for brevity).  I can't figure out how to reference an image?

Comment: @panofish Thanks for your response!  We must have a version or installation discrepancy, because the code as posted works fine for me (I just double-checked by copy-pasting the post).  I'll make those changes, though, in case other folks have the issue.  I added an example image and execution code for testing.  Was there anything else that made it incomplete?

Comment: I should also mention that it needs running under Python 2 because of the `Tkinter` import in ajsutil.py.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problems

For Python 2 and 3 compatibility `xrange` would need to be defined in
both versions, e.g.:

```
try:
    xrange
except NameError:
    xrange = range
```

Also, in Python 3 I get a lot of errors because `mod` isn't set:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qt.py", line 64, in keyPressEvent
    self.modEvent.emit([x*self.bs/2 for x in mod])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mod' referenced before assignment
```

I'd address that with a method like this:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    """Move the box with arrow keys."""
    if self.mouseOn:
        return

    mod = {
        QtCore.Qt.Key_Up: [0, -1],
        QtCore.Qt.Key_Down: [0, 1],
        QtCore.Qt.Key_Left: [-1, 0],
        QtCore.Qt.Key_Right: [1, 0]
    }.get(event.key())

    if not mod:
        return

    self.modEvent.emit([x * self.bs / 2 for x in mod])
```

Or so; exit early, use declarative syntax (which looks a bit cleaner
than a lot of `if`s and only use `mod` when it actually has a value.

The `save` method will raise an error if the user didn't select a
filename, so check the return value of `getSaveFileName` before
destructuring it:

```
def save(self):
    """Save the big image to an image file."""
    selection = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
    if selection:
        self.view.px.pixmap().save(selection[0])
```

Zoom level 25% is showing artifacts when the picture isn't big enough.
I guess that's somewhat expected, but I'd still rather catch that
instead.

## Style

- Obviously [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
  Especially whitespace and abbrevations bug me: `grn` is so not more
  readable than `green`.
- Some variables are unused, e.g. `smbytefunc` and `tobytefunc`.
- Instead of `clamp` you can use
  [`numpy.clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).
- Loops with `range(len(...))` are probably better written with
  `enumerate` instead.  If you have a list of images you can also just
  iterate over the contents, instead of using the indexes from
  `range(number_of_images)`.
- It is less error-prone to keep just one list of
  images/widgets/... than to keep the number of things as a separate
  variable; e.g. both `nimgs` *and* `smid` is more likely to get out of
  sync with each other.  If you want a shortcut, maybe use a property
  for `nimgs` instead.
- Using both Tk *and* Qt is not nice; (if you're already using Qt, than)
  try to minimise the number of (additional) dependencies in your
  application.  I found
  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893328/qt-getting-the-screen-resolution-without-the-extended-monitor)
  for the screen size and it seems to work fine for this setup.

The separation between the `SubView` and the main application window is
good enough I think.  The main view though does quite a lot; it might
make sense to move part of the update logic into the separate windows
and create a new class for them instead.

## Performance

For the slowness I'd always use a profiler to figure out what's
happening there.  So with handy dandy `cProfile` in hand, let's see what
takes so much time (`python -mcProfile -oqt.profile -stottime qt.py`
then set zoom to 50% and wiggle the mouse around a lot):

```
qt.profile% stats
Tue Aug  4 23:41:39 2015    qt.profile

         96226 function calls (93379 primitive calls) in 10.468 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    4.468    4.468   10.158   10.158 {built-in method exec_}
     1731    3.882    0.002    3.882    0.002 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
     1724    0.548    0.000    4.451    0.003 /usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:53(_mean)
      865    0.425    0.000    0.540    0.001 ./ajsutil.py:39(bytescale)
     4353    0.357    0.000    0.370    0.000 {built-in method array}
      287    0.193    0.001    5.678    0.020 qt.py:292(updateView)
      288    0.064    0.000    0.064    0.000 {built-in method showMessage}
      866    0.058    0.000    0.058    0.000 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    26/23    0.053    0.002    0.057    0.002 {built-in method load_dynamic}
      862    0.045    0.000    4.810    0.006 ./ajsutil.py:53(downsamp)
        1    0.035    0.035    0.035    0.035 {built-in method create}
      120    0.030    0.000    0.030    0.000 {built-in method loads}
        4    0.027    0.007    0.027    0.007 {built-in method show}
      865    0.025    0.000    0.025    0.000 {built-in method setColorTable}
     2586    0.022    0.000    0.022    0.000 {method 'reshape' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
      862    0.018    0.000    0.031    0.000 /usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py:792(tile)
      862    0.012    0.000    0.012    0.000 ./ajsutil.py:61(<listcomp>)
        1    0.010    0.010   10.277   10.277 qt.py:87(__init__)
```

And so forth.  I've sorted by `tottime` to see the actual running time
in functions.

So what stands out?  `downsamp` and `bytescale` I'd say.

Let's start with `downsamp`.  I guessed that the `mean` calls at the end
where a problem, because `mean` comes up in the stats as well; searching
for that gives me
[this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17403375/2769043),
which adapted to the code gives a bit of a boost:

```
return new.mean(axis=tuple(range(ndim * 2 - 1, 0, -2)))
```

That said, without optimised routines that are destructive (i.e. don't
copy so much image data around) I assume you won't get much of a speedup
out of all this.  I'd suggest to look into
e.g. [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) instead of implementing
this yourself.

Oh and now that I think of it:  I'd rather (up/down)scale the images
*once* when the setting changes and then only index into the already
scaled version instead of doing that on every mouse move.

Comment: @EthanBierlein `xrange` isn't defined in Python 3, which is why this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your lovely answer!!  I've not yet learned how to use a profiler with Python, this is very informative.  Your point about doing the up/down scaling once is well made, that may make things much better!  It looks like those really are the culprit - my main reason for not thinking so immediately was because I initially implemented a version of this in Tkinter (using the exact same `ajsutil.py`), and it performed *much* faster.  Do you have any ideas why that would be?  This is me trying to get away from Tkinter (as you so rightly point out, using both = blech).

Comment: @Ajean sorry, unfortunately I don't really have an idea about Tk, or why using Qt is much slower. It might be some conversions going on that aren't done in Tk, or so; but for that you'd have to ask an expert on that.